# Recursive UNTAR / UNZIP

Tags: tar, zip

i get zip files or tar files to work upon.

The zip /tar file may have a several directories and sub-directories which in-turn may contain tar files / zip files

I need to untar / unzip those which are present inside the parent Tar / Zip at their respective directory locations and then delete the tar / zip file.

Below is what i could achieve but the problem is it untars / unzips only the parent tar/zip and not the those which are present inside the zip / tar.

```
found=1

while [ $found -eq 1 ]
do
    found=0
    for compressfile in *.tar *.zip
    do     
        found=1
        echo "EXTRACT THIS:"$compressfile
        tar xvf "$compressfile" && rm -rf "$compressfile"
        unzip "$compressfile" && rm -rf "$compressfile"
        exc=$?

        if [ $exc -ne 0 ]
        then
            exit $exc
        fi
    done
done
```

Note: the Tar file may contain both Tar and Zip files. Likewise The Zip may contain Zip or Tar files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note, this is untested, but this might be close to what you're looking for:

```
#!/bin/bash

doExtract() {
    local compressfile="${1}"
    local rc=0

    pushd "$(dirname "${compressfile}")" &> /dev/null
    if [[ "${compressfile}" == *.tar ]]; then
        echo "Extracting TAR: ${compressfile}"
        tar -xvf "$(basename ${compressfile})"
        rc=$?
    elif [[ "${compressfile}" == *.zip ]]; then
        echo "Extracting ZIP: ${compressfile}"
        unzip "$(basename "${compressfile}")"
        rc=$?
    fi
    popd &> /dev/null

    if [[ ${rc} -eq 0 ]]; then
        # You can remove the -i when you're sure this is doing what you want
        rm -i "${compressfile}"
    fi

    return ${rc}
}

found=1

while [[ ${found} -eq 1 ]]; do
    found=0

    for compressfile in $(find . -type f -name '*.tar' -o -name '*.zip'); do
        found=1
        doExtract "${compressfile}"
        rc=$?
        if [[ $rc -ne 0 ]]; then
             exit ${rc}
        fi
    done
done
```

Edit: This script recursively looks for files ending in `.tar` or `.zip`.  Without the availability of the `-C` option to `tar`, I use `pushd`/`popd` to change to the directory containing the files, extract them in that directory, then return to the previous directory.

Comment: Changed ind . -type f -name '*.tar' '*.zip' to ind . -type f -name '*.tar' -o -name '*.zip' to get over the error. Also tar -C is not supported with my tar. One more issue i see is that it does not seem to be deleting tar files in sub-folders. It deletes only those in the parent tar ball directory.  uname -a is: SunOS 5.10 sun4v sparc

Comment: I modified the script to address your comments above.  Do you get any errors from `rm`?  It could simply be that the `tar` or `unzip` is failing -- the file is only removed if those operations are successful.